# Is it possible to use pam_mount with gvfs and how?

Tags: pam, gvfs

Is it possible to use `gvfs` with `pam_mount`, using user's password for the mounting command ?

How would one achieve that ?

Reading the documentation, it seems this might be a good start, but no way to inject password this way.

```
<volume user="%(USER)" fstype="fuse" path="gvfs-mount smb://%(USER)@NAME/SHARE" mountpoint="/run/user/%(USERUID)/gvfs" />
```

Comment: try to add some option `options="username=yourUserName"`

Comment: Username is already taken care of as seen in the snippet, my struggle is with the password and "domain".